# No consigo poner en un banner en una activity

Tags: java, android, admob

estoy en proceso de creación de una aplicación para android (uso android studio para programarla) y me encuentro con el siguiente problema, que no se como solucionarlo:

Estoy intentando poner un banner de admob en esta clase de java que extiende Fragment, el objetivo de esta clase sería más o menos como un tweet line de un determinada cuenta 'x' de twitter, pero no consigo que se vea en pantalla el banner publicitario y además al inicializarlo me está dando el siguiente error:

```
Cannot resolve 'findViewByID(int)'
```

El error no se si viene a la hora de llamar a inicializar el anuncio o por lo contrario el error está en la ubicación del código de del banner xml dentro del LinearLayout (o ambas cosas que también es posible).

Mi código de la clase de java es este:

```
public class UserTimelineFragment extends Fragment {
    private Context context;
    private RecyclerView userTimelineRecyclerView;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;
    private TweetTimelineRecyclerViewAdapter adapter;
    AdView mAdView;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        this.context = context;
    }

    public static UserTimelineFragment newInstance() {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        UserTimelineFragment fragment = new UserTimelineFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.user_timeline_fragment, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        setUpSwipeRefreshLayout(view);
        setUpRecyclerView(view);
        loadUserTimeline();

        mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView2);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }

    private void setUpRecyclerView(@NonNull View view) {
        userTimelineRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.user_timeline_recycler_view);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context);
        userTimelineRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    }

    private void loadUserTimeline() {
        UserTimeline userTimeline = new UserTimeline.Builder()
                .screenName("prueba")
                .includeReplies(false)
                .includeRetweets(false)
                .maxItemsPerRequest(8)
                .build();
        adapter = new TweetTimelineRecyclerViewAdapter.Builder(context)
                .setTimeline(userTimeline)
                .build();
        userTimelineRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private void setUpSwipeRefreshLayout(View view) {
        swipeRefreshLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.user_swipe_refresh_layout);
        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                if (adapter == null)
                    return;
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
                adapter.refresh(new Callback<TimelineResult<Tweet>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void success(Result<TimelineResult<Tweet>> result) {
                        TimelineResult<Tweet> filteredTweets = getFilteredListOfTweets(result.data);
                        //on success response make refreshing false
                        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Tweets actualizados.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
                        // Toast or some other action
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Error al actualizar los tweets.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }

    private static TimelineResult<Tweet> getFilteredListOfTweets(TimelineResult<Tweet> timelineResult){
        TimelineResult<Tweet> filteredTweets = new TimelineResult<>(null, Collections.<Tweet>emptyList());
        for (int i=0;i<timelineResult.items.size();i++){
            if (timelineResult.items.get(i).source.contains("cupón")){
                filteredTweets.items.add(timelineResult.items.get(i));
            }
        }
        return filteredTweets;
    }
}
```

Y mi código en xml de esta clase de java es el siguiente:

```
<androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:screenOrientation="unspecified"
    android:id="@+id/user_swipe_refresh_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <Button
            .../>
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/user_timeline_recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="624dp" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/empty"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/no_tweets" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_id"
        ads:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        ads:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        ads:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        ads:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
</androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Gracias por la ayuda de antemano.

Comment: Como dijeron en la respuesta, el problema es como estas llamando al banner. Al ser un Fragment, necesitas declarar cada objeto bajo un `view` y luego proseguir con `findViewById`

Comment: Adjunto otro modo con otros elementos: 
`hola= (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.hola);`

Comment: Cannot resolve 'findViewByID(int)' :
se refiere a que no puede resolver el método, ya sea porque este no existe o la clase desde la cual se obtiene no lo contiene, el nombre del método debe ser  'findViewById(int)' : @Gorpe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema está en la ubicación del objeto que llamas con `findViewById()`. por lo que veo, estás llamando al banner:

```
mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView2);
```

Deberías localizarlo por la vista `view`. Y te quedaría así;

```
mAdView = view.findViewById(R.id.adView2);
```

Lo mismo debes hacer para localizar todos los objetos que están en ese mismo `xml`.
Espero te resuelva el problema, si no, aumento esta respuesta.

Comment: Perfecto! Era justamente esto muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

El problema

> Cannot resolve 'findViewByID(int)'

**se refiere a que no puede resolver el método, ya sea porque este no existe o la clase desde la cual se obtiene no lo contiene.**

En este caso el problema es simplemente que el nombre es incorrecto:

```
findViewByID( )
```

debe ser (ver la diferencia en la letra "D"):

```
findViewById( )
```

---

Después de asegurar escribir correctamente el nombre del método, si tu vista con id `adView2`, se encuentra dentro del layout `user_timeline_fragment.xml` , entonces debes obtener la referencia de la vista que buscas, dentro de la vista que se carga en `onViewCreated()` :

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    ...
    ...
    ...

    mAdView = view.findViewById(R.id.adView2);
    ...
    ...
    ...
}
```

Comment: Perfecto! Era justamente esto muchas gracias a los dos

Comment: Excelente, saludos @Gorpe